Self Signed certificates in kotlin multiplatform compose with ktor
I am currently building an android/ios mobile application with kotlin multiplatform compose. This application uses a django server for it's backend. The server has some self signed certificates that block me from doing request through https. Http request are working great, but I need https to test on external devices and also for when the app is going to be deployed. I use OkHttp and darwin for my ktor HttpClient engine. I'm new to mobile dev/kotlin and feeling a bit lost
I have tried following the documentation present on ktor for setting up ssl (https://ktor.io/docs/client-ssl.html), but I don't understand what I'm supposed to do. I have my certificate, but it isn't in a keystore and I don't know how to store it in one.
I have also tried following this tutorial (https://alistairsykes.medium.com/how-to-trust-all-ssl-certificates-with-kmm-and-ktor-8f686aec0d09) to trust all certificate as a test. I wasn't able to make it work.
